# Local group policy editor: Out of date version?

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy, mmc, gpedit

I've been trying to use gpedit.msc recently but I haven't been having much success. Sometimes the policy editor freezes when I press "apply" (the policy does still apply though), and I can't seem to find the link to apply policies to certain users only - only for all users: [see here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/151415-group-policy-apply-specific-user-group.html) for an example of what I think it should be like...

And before you ask, I'm running Windows 7 Professional. I've checked the management console and the "Help>About group policy..." link shows I'm using version 1.0 of the snap-in? Is that right or have I somehow got an out-of-date version? And if it makes a difference, I used anytime upgrade from Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: It is correct..

Comment: You mean the version? Why is it randomly crashing then?